# How to import gradle project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build, importerror

I have clone fido project from `https://github.com/hs14m2b/UAF.git` here locally.

Then while importing the project using eclipse import exsiting gradle project it's failing with following errors.

[image]

Comment: did you try to perform a build from command line ? `gradle build` or `./gradlew build` if the project is configured with the wrapper.

Comment: No I didn't tried with `gradle build` or `./gradlew build`, but I will try to build using that and then will try import it.

Comment: But ideally while importing it should not fail right?.

Comment: it should not fail, if the project is valid (can be confirmed by executing build from command line) and if you have proper Eclipse version/plugin installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is android project so if you import using android studio you won't throw any exception.

see [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/)